# Memory Allocation without Linked List

Tags: c, pointers

Say I have this struct:

```
struct Book
{
   int book_id;
   struct Book *book_ptr;
};
/* navigation pointers */
struct Book *front;
struct Book *rear;
```

and I want to add a new `Book` to my memory, so I have this function:

```
void add_book() {
    struct Book *temp;  
    temp = (struct Book*)malloc(sizeof(struct Book));    
    temp->book_id = t;
    t++;    
    temp->book_ptr = NULL;       
    if (rear  ==  NULL)
    {
        front = temp;
        rear = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->book_ptr = temp;
        rear = temp;
    }        
}
```

and if I want a list of my `Books`:

```
void see_all_the_books()
{
    struct Book *temp;     
    temp = front;    
    if (front  ==  NULL)
    {
        printf("> YOU HAVEN'T ADDED ANY BOOK YET\n");
    }
    while (temp)
    {
        printf("Book #%d\n", temp->book_id);
        temp = temp->book_ptr;
    }
}
```

Fairly straightforward, and it works. 
**But** what if I don't want to use Linked List. What I want to do is to move my `rear` pointer one block every time that I am making a new book.

Then my struct would be something like this:

```
struct Book
{
   int book_id;
};
/* navigation pointers */
struct Book *front;
struct Book *rear;
```

and I need to move my pointer 1 block every time I want to add a `Book`:

```
 void add_book() {
    struct Book *temp;
    temp = (struct Book*)malloc(sizeof(struct Book));

    temp->book_id = t;
    t++;

    if (rear  ==  NULL)
    {
        printf("Your FIRST book has been added\n");        
        front = temp; 
        rear = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        rear++;         // MOVED TO NEXT BLOCK
        rear = temp;    // OBVIOUSLY WRONG      
        printf("ANOTHER book has been added\n"); 
    }        
}
```

What do I need to change in my last code?

Comment: In other words, you want to use an array.

Comment: you would need to change front and rear to struct Book **, allocate front in the beginning as space for an initial amount of Book * and then detect and reallocate as you approach the boundary

Comment: Or just use `struct Book **books;` and allocate the pointers with `calloc` (to initialize to `NULL`). (e.g. `books = calloc (numbooks, sizeof *books);`, then allocate for each struct added (e.g. `books[i] = malloc (sizeof **books);` ). You know how many books you have with `i` **OR** simply iterate over allocated pointers (e.g. `while (books[i]) { ..do stuff..; i++; }` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of subtle issue raised by your approach of allocating a new `struct Book` in `add_book`. This is nothing wrong with doing it this way, in fact it is quite common, but you must take care how you pass the required parameters to `add_book`. To successfully create an array of pointers in `main()` and use `add_book` to allocate for each new book added, you must pass the **address of your array of pointers** to `add_book` to handle reallocation in the event you need more pointers. You also need a way to pass and keep track of the number of pointers you have allocated **and** the current maximum number of pointers available. Therefore a basic declaration for `add_book` would look something like:

```
struct Book *add_book (struct Book ***book, int id, size_t *idx, size_t *nmax);
```

Where `***book` is the address of your array of pointers declared in `main()`, `id` is the new value to assign to `book_id`, `idx` is the current index for the `struct Book` to add and `nmax` is the number of pointers available to fill.

**Note:** you are passing a pointer to both `idx` and `nmax` to your `add_book` function. This allows you to increment/change their values in `add_book` while having thier updated values available in `main()`. A full prototye for`add_book` could look like:

```
struct Book *add_book (struct Book ***book, int id, size_t *idx, size_t *nmax)
{
    if (!book || !*book)   return NULL;

    size_t n = *idx;
    (*book)[*idx] = xcalloc (1, sizeof **book);

    (*book)[*idx]-> book_id = id;
    (*idx)++;

    if (*idx == *nmax) {    /* realloc if nmax reached, update nmax */
        void *tmp = realloc (*book, *nmax * 2 * sizeof tmp);
        if (!tmp) {
            fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
            return NULL;
        }
        *book = tmp;  /* use memset to initialize all new pointers NULL */
        memset (*book + *nmax, 0, *nmax * sizeof tmp);
        *nmax *= 2;
    }

    return (*book)[n];
}
```

**Note:** since you passed the *address of* `Book` to the function, you must dereference `Book` (i.e. `*book`) in `add_book` in order to properly work with the array of pointers.  Also note `xcalloc` is just an error checking function that calls `calloc` to prevent cluttering the logic with testing the return of `calloc` each allocation.

**Note for Windows:** The compiler in visual studio does not know that `__func__` is simply a macro to return the function name. So if you are using visual studio to compile the code, just replace `__func__` with `"function name"`.

A full example will help. The following puts all the pieces together necessary to use an array of pointers to hold your collection of `struct Book`. Note: during the example below, the maximum number of books is defined as `8`, but `10 book_id`'s are given forcing the reallocation of `Book` in `add_book` when `*idx == *nmax` where both `*idx & *nmax = 8`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NBOOKS 8

struct Book {
    int book_id;
};

void *xcalloc (size_t n, size_t s);
struct Book *add_book (struct Book ***book, int id, size_t *idx, size_t *nmax);

int main (void) {

    size_t idx = 0;
    size_t nbooks = 0;
    size_t nmax = NBOOKS;
    int id = 0;
    struct Book **Book = NULL;

    /* create NBOOKS pointers to struct Book */
    Book = xcalloc (NBOOKS, sizeof *Book);

    /* read integer input from stdin */
    while (scanf ("%d", &id) == 1)
        add_book (&Book, id, &idx, &nmax);

    nbooks = idx;   /* save the number of books added */

    /* print the book_id for each book */
    for (idx = 0; idx < nbooks; idx++)
        printf ("  Book[%2zu] : %d\n", idx, Book[idx]->book_id);

    /* free all allocated memory */
    for (idx = 0; idx < nbooks; idx++)
        free (Book[idx]);
    free (Book);

    return 0;
}

/* add one struct Book to array of pointers to Book with book_id = 'id'
 * NOTE: since you must protect against writing beyond the last pointer 
 * you must pass the ADDRESS OF Book (the reason for ***) in the event a
 * realloc occurs. Otherwise the address of Book in main() will never
 * reflect the reallocation. (pointers to idx and nmax are passed so their
 * updated values are available in main() ).
 */
struct Book *add_book (struct Book ***book, int id, size_t *idx, size_t *nmax)
{
    if (!book || !*book)   return NULL;

    size_t n = *idx;
    (*book)[*idx] = xcalloc (1, sizeof **book);

    (*book)[*idx]-> book_id = id;
    (*idx)++;

    if (*idx == *nmax) {    /* realloc if nmax reached, update nmax */
        void *tmp = realloc (*book, *nmax * 2 * sizeof tmp);
        if (!tmp) {
            fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
            return NULL;
        }
        *book = tmp;  /* use memset to initialize all new pointers NULL */
        memset (*book + *nmax, 0, *nmax * sizeof tmp);
        *nmax *= 2;
    }

    return (*book)[n];
}


/** xcalloc allocates memory using calloc and validates the return.
 *  xcalloc allocates memory and reports an error if the value is
 *  null, returning a memory address only if the value is nonzero
 *  freeing the caller of validating within the body of code.
 */
void *xcalloc (size_t n, size_t s)
{
    register void *memptr = calloc (n, s);
    if (memptr == 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n", __func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return memptr;
}
```

**Sampe Input (10 int)**

```
$ cat dat/10int_nl.txt
8572
-2213
6434
16330
3034
12346
4855
16985
11250
1495
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_book_simple <dat/10int_nl.txt
  Book[ 0] : 8572
  Book[ 1] : -2213
  Book[ 2] : 6434
  Book[ 3] : 16330
  Book[ 4] : 3034
  Book[ 5] : 12346
  Book[ 6] : 4855
  Book[ 7] : 16985
  Book[ 8] : 11250
  Book[ 9] : 1495
```

**Memory Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/struct_book_simple <dat/10int_nl.txt
==9039== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9039== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9039== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9039== Command: ./bin/struct_book_simple
==9039==
  Book[ 0] : 8572
 <snip>
  Book[ 9] : 1495
==9039==
==9039== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9039==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9039==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 12 frees, 272 bytes allocated
==9039==
==9039== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9039==
==9039== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9039== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of pointers, each one will point to a single book. It will require a bit of changing in your code as front and rear will no longer be necessary.

```
int maxbooks = somenumber;
Struct book *books= malloc(maxbooks*sizeof(struct book));
int numbooks = 0;


addbook()
{
(books+numbooks)->book_id = t;
numbooks++;
}
```