# Moving Pointer by 1 block of struct

Tags: c, pointers

I have this piece of code:

```
struct Book
{
  int book_id;
};

/* navigator pointer */
struct Book *rear;

struct Book *temp;
/* making memory for storing First book */
temp = (struct Book*)malloc(sizeof(struct Book));
temp->book_id = 111;
rear = temp;

struct Book *temp2;
/* making memory for storing the Second book */
temp2 = (struct Book*)malloc(sizeof(struct Book));
temp2->book_id = 222;

/* I want to point to the second book with one block after my first base pointer */

struct Book *rear2 = rear + 1;
rear2 = temp2;

printf("---> #%d\n", (rear+1)->book_id);    
int i;
for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("i = %d  ", i);        
    printf("---> #%d\n", (rear+i)->book_id);
}
```

so I am expecting to get this as the result:

```
i = 0  ---> #111
i = 1  ---> #222
```

but I am getting this, because apparently I failed to point to my second `Book` correctly:

```
i = 0  ---> #111
i = 1  ---> #0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no guarantee that subsequent calls to `malloc` will return packed, consecutive memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are accessing memory that you are not supposed to. Your program is subject to undefined behavior.

`rear` points to only one `struct Book`. `rear + 1` points to memory beyond what you allocated.

I don't know why you think `rear+1` is the same as `rear2`. `rear` and `rear2` point to memory that was returned by two different calls to `malloc` and are unrelated.

Comment: hm, so is there any way I can move `rear` by one block, make my book and point that `rear+1` to that second book?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by using `realloc`.

Comment: You may find a very similar question discussed here [**Memory Allocation without Linked List**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32929341/memory-allocation-without-linked-list/32930200#32930200)